# how to switch to active call screen

Tags: android

When a call is answered, you go to the active call screen (it has buttons to End the call, display the Dialpad, Mute the call etc)

Let's say the user navigates to my app while a call is ongoing.  Is there mechanism to programmatically return to the ongoing call?  I'd like to have a button in my app so that if there is an active call and my app is running in the foreground then the user can press the button and return to the active call screen.

Will I need a BroadcastReceiver?  Do I return to the ongoing call screen with an Intent?  That doesn't seem right.  I thought Intents started new activities and didn't return you to Activities that are already running.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Mark

Comment: Have you found some way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is on top of the in call app in the Activity stack you should be able to call `finish()` on your own Activity which will leave the in call app on the top of the stack again, and thus it will be what is shown on the screen.

Also fwiw, I am not certain you need to provide the user with a way to get back within your Activity. They should be able to pull down the notification bar and click the "In Call" entry that gets placed in there to get back.

Comment: Pulling down the notification bar can be tricky to do for some people.  

What I'd like to create is a hotkey that switches between my app and the ongoing phone call screen.  If you are running my app, pressing the key will take you to the ongoing call.  If you are at the ongoing call screen, pressing the key will take you back to my app.  This all assumes my app is running and there is an ongoing call.

Comment: AFAIK there is no legit way for you to add a button to the incoming call screen, so if you can make it work it can only be one way, from your app to the phone screen, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Android O, at least. Simple intent to `ACTION_CALL_BUTTON` makes the work:

```
  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
  startActivity(callIntent);
```